# Find Tron Energy Estimate Before transaction?

Tags: tron

i want to calculate energy before transaction in tron blockchain, So we can show end users fees for transaction before transaction in app. But i am din't able to find any docs or any function any api  for this.   please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution https://developers.tron.network/docs/set-feelimit#how-to-estimate-energy-consumption

An example is listed as follows:

```
$ curl -X POST  https://nile.trongrid.io/wallet/triggerconstantcontract -d '{
    "owner_address": "TTGhREx2pDSxFX555NWz1YwGpiBVPvQA7e",
    "contract_address": "TVSvjZdyDSNocHm7dP3jvCmMNsCnMTPa5W",
    "function_selector": "transfer(address,uint256)",
    "parameter": "0000000000000000000000002ce5de57373427f799cc0a3dd03b841322514a8c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c68000",
    "visible": true
}'
```

It returns:

```
{
   ……
   "result": {
       "result": true
   },
   "energy_used": 46236,
   "energy_penalty": 32983,
   ……


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this isn't too late :)

###### This documentation should cover your need i believe:

https://tronprotocol.github.io/documentation-en/mechanism-algorithm/resource/#2-how-to-set-fee-limit-caller-must-read

Tron GET Endpoint: `https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{contract}/transactions?only_confirmed=true` you may add `&limit=` your preferred stop point [type=int e.g 200].

From the data returned you can get the `energy_usage_total` for each then average it.

This gives insight into the energy consumed for the x numbers of latest transactions you requested for.

Comment: I'm still surprised this answer was initially downvoted. Here's a github gist implementing what i'd stated here: https://gist.github.com/andelf/65121c2c7f81e773f5f879d9992843f8

It's simple and straight forward enough: Get `energy_usage_total` for `x` numbers of transactions, average it, then convert it using the tron-energy price value. C'est fini

Comment: What is this user doesn't have the transactions yet?

Comment: @deathangel908 I don't think it matters if a new wallet address has recorded a transaction or not. We are looking up the TRX contract directly to find `energy_usage_total` on the network